# Write a log file in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, csv, nsfilemanager

I'm developing an application that use the `CLLocationManager` to save a GPX track. Additionally I would write down on a `*.csv` file the location for debug, but unfortunately the file will the written only at the start and at the end of the recording session. I guess because the application is on foreground while user start and stop the recording and the rest of the time is on background.

Code to call the write on file:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        if (isDebug || ([location verticalAccuracy] >= 0 && [location horizontalAccuracy] >= 0))
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
                [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
                NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:location.timestamp];
                [Utils writeCompleteGPSWithActivityID:_currentActivity.uniqueIdentifier status:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,0,0\n", dateString, location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude,location.altitude, location.speed, location.course, location.horizontalAccuracy, location.verticalAccuracy]];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The method that write some the CSV file:

```
+ (void)writeCompleteGPSWithActivityID:(NSString *)activityID status:(NSString *)status
{
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@_ios_completed.csv", activityID];
    NSString *filePath = [[Utils getGPXDirectory] stringByAppendingString:fileName];

    if (fileName == nil)
        return;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        [Utils createCompleteGPSFile:activityID];
    }
    NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    [fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];

    [fileHandler writeData:[status dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandler closeFile];
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting on the Xcode console? Your CSV code looks fine...

Comment: I've no error on the console. Simply after a recording my CSV file has only the records of the start and some of the finish, i think in the period that the application in in foreground

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case then you don't have a CSV writing problem, you will have to enable background modes in your application. Specifically the background location mode. That will ensure your app is running even when after starting location user puts it in the background. No changes required to CSV writing code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi vishalv2050, unfortunately I receive and use all the location in background, all the application background mode is working like a charm. The only problem is with this writing CSV task...

Comment: How do you know the location is working fine ? do you have logs for the location points received ?

Comment: because I use the location to create a GPX file, and It works like a charm. The same location will be put on the csv file and it's not working. the only difference is that for the GPX I save the location on an array and then save it all when user press save, for the csv, every time i receive a location i add a line to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that every file stored on an iOS device is associated with a data protection type which determine when the file can be read from and written to.

Have you checked which data protection attribute is associated with the file you are trying to write into?

If its protection attribute is set e.g. to `NSFileProtectionComplete` it would mean that calling `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath` when the device is locked will result in a null handle.